How to achieve typed dependency injection in Python while avoiding circular imports?
I'm working on a Python project and want to implement dependency injection with type safety. Here's a simplified version of my current structure:
a.py :
   class A:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

    def run(self):
        print(self.b.get_text()) # blindly calling the function because b is not typed

b.py :
from app.a import A

class B:
    def run(self):
        a = A(self)
        a.run()

    def get_text(self):
        return "hello world"

main.py :
from app.b import B

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    b.run()

I want to properly type the b argument in A's constructor (a.py). However, as expected importing B directly causes a circular import.
What I've tried:

Protocols: This works but leads to a lot of code duplication,
especially when injecting multiple classes.

Abstract Base Classes (ABC): Also works, but if a subclass adds new
properties, type checking becomes difficult because the injected class cannot reflect those properties accurately.

if TYPE_CHECKING voodoo is often recommended (Python type hinting without cyclic imports), could be a solution but looks very hacky.


Question:
What is the most maintainable and type-safe approach to dependency injection in Python that avoids circular imports ?
Are there any best practices or design patterns that handle this situation more elegantly ?
Thank you

if TYPE_CHECKING it is.
